# Facebook Messenger disable page notifications on postback

Tags: facebook, notifications, bots, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I am trying to find an answer if its possible to disable page notifications on facebook when a user clicks a button of type **postback**.

When you hit a postback button the button title appears as message in messenger and the payload of the button is sent to the webhook address. However a support team for the linked facebook page would get a notification that there is a new conversation or message for their page.

I would like to get notifications only if a user writes some input text by himself. Otherwise it is really difficult for a support team to differentiate between important user questions and uninteresting postbacks because when many users clicks these buttons for example to subscribe or unsubscribe news channels the support team doesn't need to know about that. But if a user writes directly to the page it is important to know that so they can respond fast. So if many users only change their subscription settings and few of them write questions to the page the support team gets spammed with notifications and the direct user input may be overlooked.

[image: FBMessenger Notification]

Thanks in advance!